# Cannot read and write files except text files

Tags: c++

I have a problem with `fread()` and `fwrite()`. I can not read and write the file.

For instance, I can not read from `D:\test.docx` and write to `C:\copy.docx`.

The file is created but when I open `C:\copy.docx` I get an error:

> We are sorry. We can not open copy.docx because we found a problem with its contents.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char fname[100];
    char to[100];

    cin >> fname;
    cin >> to;

    FILE *fp   = fopen(fname,"r");
    FILE *copy = fopen(to,"w");

    if (fp != NULL && copy != NULL) {
        char buff[1024]={0};
        int nread = fread(buff,1,1024,fp);

        cout << "Sending \n";
        fwrite(buff, 1, nread,copy);

        cout << "File transfer completed\n";
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(copy);
    }
    else cout << "ERROR\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: If you don't want it as text, stop reading it into a `char *` buffer.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand you

Comment: I don't know anything about docx and I don't have one handy to check but they might be binary files and not text. If that's the case then you need to open the files in binary mode with fopen(fname, "rb") and fopen(to,"wb") .

Comment: Also, how big is the file? Since you're not looping you're only ever copying at most 1024 bytes.

Comment: file size 12 kilobytes

Comment: Is it possible to first find out the file size? If you know, you can write

Comment: You're using a string data type (`char buff[1024]`). That's for text. Use a more proper data type. If you treat binary data like text, it causes issues (as you can see) - the fix is to stop treating them as text.

Comment: I just wrote the manual file size, everything worked fine, now I just had to know the file size in advance

Comment: what is the correct data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the files in binary mode, and you need to loop through the source file until EOF is reached.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char fname[100];
    char to[100];

    cin >> setw(100) >> fname;
    cin >> setw(100) >> to;

    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    if (fp)
    {
        FILE *copy = fopen(to, "wb");
        if (copy)
        {
            unsigned char buff[1024];
            int nread;

            cout << "Sending\n";

            while ((nread = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), fp)) > 0)
            {
                if (fwrite(buff, 1, nread, copy) < nread)
                    break;
            }

            if (ferror(fp) || ferror(copy))
                cerr << "File transfer failed\n";
            else
                cout << "File transfer completed\n";

            fclose(copy);
        }
        else
            cerr << "Error creating dest file\n";

        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
        cerr << "Error opening source file\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

That said, the above is a C-ish way to copy a file. A C++-ish way would look more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string fname;
    string to;

    cin >> fname;
    cin >> to;

    ifstream fp(fname.c_str(), ios::binary);
    if (fp.is_open())
    {
        ofstream copy(to.c_str(), ios::binary);
        if (copy.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Sending\n";

            copy.exceptions(ios::badbit | ios::failbit);
            try
            {
                copy << fp.rdbuf();
                cout << "File transfer completed\n";
            }
            catch(const ios_base::failure&)
            {
                cerr << "File transfer failed\n";
            }

            copy.close();
        }
        else
            cerr << "Error creating dest file\n";

        fp.close();
    }
    else
        cerr << "Error opening source file\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```